# Getting the fragment from the current activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

Hey guys I have fragment

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.recordings, container, false);
}
```

Here is my layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/recordinglayout">
```

How would I get this fragment object without adding it to my activity? Or add something, for instance like a button to fragment's layout from activity class?

Answer (score 0):

An activity cannot reference a fragment that has not been instantiated somehow. You can instantiate a fragment via the fragment tag in xml, or create one programmatically in Java.

I suggest you take a close look at the documentation on [creating (and referencing) fragments](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html) :)